# bitset::operator[] == false/true or bitset::test?

Tags: c++, bitset

Is using bitset::operator[] equivalent to using bitset::test or is there some underlying optimization?

That is, are these two loops equivalent?

Using bitset::operator[]:

```
static const int UP = 0;
static const int DOWN = 1;

for(int i = 1; i < KEY_MAX; ++i) {
    if(_handler && (_prevKey[i] == UP && _curKey[i] == DOWN)) {
        _handler->EnqueueEvent(new KeyboardKeyDownEvent(i));
    }
    if(_handler && (_prevKey[i] == DOWN && _curKey[i] == DOWN)) {
        _handler->EnqueueEvent(new KeyboardKeyPressEvent(i));
    }
    if(_handler && (_prevKey[i] == DOWN && _curKey[i] == UP)) {
        _handler->EnqueueEvent(new KeyboardKeyUpEvent(i));
    }
}
```

Using bitset::test():

```
static const bool UP = false;
static const bool  DOWN = true;

for(int i = 1; i < KEY_MAX; ++i) {
    if(_handler && (_prevKey.test(i) == UP && _curKey.test(i) == DOWN)) {
        _handler->EnqueueEvent(new KeyboardKeyDownEvent(i));
    }
    if(_handler && (_prevKey.test(i) == DOWN && _curKey.test(i) == DOWN)) {
        _handler->EnqueueEvent(new KeyboardKeyPressEvent(i));
    }
    if(_handler && (_prevKey.test(i) == DOWN && _curKey.test(i) == UP)) {
        _handler->EnqueueEvent(new KeyboardKeyUpEvent(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the C++03 standard, §23.3.5.2/39-41:

> ```
> bool test(size_t pos) const;
> ```
>
> **Requires:** `pos` is valid
>   **Throws:** `out_of_range` if `pos` does not correspond to a valid bit position.
>   **Returns:** `true` if the bit at position `pos` in `*this` has the value one.

§23.3.5.2/46-48:

> ```
> bool operator[](size_t pos) const;
> ```
>
> **Requires:** `pos` is valid.
>   **Throws:** nothing.
>   **Returns:** `test(pos)`.

§23.3.5.2/49-51:

> ```
> bitset<N>::reference operator[](size_t pos);
> ```
>
> **Requires:** `pos` is valid.
>   **Throws:** nothing.
>   **Returns:** An object of type `bitset<N>::reference` such that `(*this)[pos] == this-
>   test(pos)`, and such that `(*this)[pos] = val` is equivalent to `this->set(pos, val)`.

So when the object is `const`, they return the same value, excepting that when `pos` is invalid `test` throws `out_of_range` while `operator[]` throws nothing. When the object is *not* `const`, the operator returns a proxy object allowing one to mutate the object's data.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike access operator ([]), The test function performs a range check on position before retrieveing the bit value. out_of_range is thrown if the position is not a valid bit position.

You can find references on:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset

Answer (score 0):

I would optimize it this way:

```
int nPrevKey, nCurKey;

for(int i = 1; i < KEY_MAX; ++i) 
{
    if(_handler)
    {
        nPrevKey = _prevKey[i];
        nCurKey = _curKey[i];

        if(nPrevKey == UP && nCurKey  == DOWN)
        {
            _handler->EnqueueEvent(new KeyboardKeyDownEvent(i));
        }
        if(nPrevKey  == DOWN && nCurKey  == DOWN)
        {
            _handler->EnqueueEvent(new KeyboardKeyPressEvent(i));
        }
        if(nPrevKey  == DOWN && nCurKey  == UP)
        {
            _handler->EnqueueEvent(new KeyboardKeyUpEvent(i));
        }
    }
}
```

And similarly the other implementation.